# Cannot bind click() event to HTML control

Tags: javascript

Here's my setup.  I'm using .NET:

1. I have a Main.aspx lets call it.  That page inherits a master page and the Master Page as usual includes the jQuery library and other includes that we use for jQuery that are global in scope
2. In Main.aspx is an HTML plain vanilla IFrame:
3. In that IFrame is another .aspx page.  Lets call it for all tense and purposes Sub.aspx
4. In Sub.aspx I've got the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <link href="Content/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="facebookPhotos-iFrameContent">
            <div>
                <p id="buttoTestContainer">                    
                    <input type="image" id="btnLogin" src="images/loginBtn.jpg" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        var loginButtonID = 'btnLogin';
        //alert(loginButtonID);                   
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            // Initialize/load the JS SDK
            // cookie is set to true to activate JS SDK cookie creation & management
            FB.init({ appId: facebookApplicationID, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: false });
            alert("got here");
            // also handles the case when they are already logged in
            $('#' + loginButtonID).click(function () {
                alert("login button was fired");
                TestLogin();
            });
            //...rest of code
        });
```

**The problem:**

When trying to debug to make sure that .click() event gets called so it binds to my control, I never get to the first alert "got here" so that I know the JS was called at least up to that point.  So not sure why.  I see absolutely no JS errors in my FireBug console either.

Comment: anyone know how I can encode this thread above to get rid of the &lt; etc,.?

Comment: You need to explain why you expect `window.fbAsyncInit` to be called.  Makes no sense.

Comment: Think about iframe as a new browser that just happens to have ability to reference the parent window - since they are both on the same site (url), thus it can call the parent, but does not by default do so to execute things like jQuery or the fb thing.

Comment: note: window.xxx is NOT the same as parent.xxx

Comment: @Mark I'm taking that right out of Facebook's own docs...they are using window

Comment: @Mark thank you for explaining this.  I knew that IFrames can reference the parent but I just do not use them often and really didn't find anything good on the web about that.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Comment: thanks for all your help...resolved it on my own finally...

Comment: lol, I love the -1...for what!  lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved. That init function should be the only thing in there. Moved all other code outside the window.fbAsyncInit because I do not want to load the others asynchronously, I want to load it after the DOM has completed. The only thing that should be loaded at the same time is the registering/Initialization of that SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Your function never executes.  Remove the `window.fbAsyncInit = function() { }` and the code will run as interpreted.  Or, use `$(document).ready(function() { });` to execute it after the DOM is ready.

Also, the Javascript libraries in the parent frame are not inherited by the child.  But you can reference them like `parent.fbAsyncInit = function() { }` or `parent.jQuery();` for example.

Comment: OK thanks.  That async is a Facebook function that they say to use because it will improve performance as anything in it will be called asynchronously.

Comment: thanks also for the hint on the IFrame stuff, it was driving me batty...even after trying to research that with .aspx

Comment: @coffee I am not familiar with that function, perhaps you need to explain more in your question about what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: @coffee As I said, if the parent frame is what references the Facebook JS library, the child frame does not have inherited access to it.  So you define the function, but it is never getting called.

Comment: All I want to happen is for that alert("got here"); to run..it's not hit as I've stated in my original post and I really don't get why.  It's just a facebook function that just initializes a JS SDK.

Comment: @coffee Comment out `FB.init` and try again

Comment: Where is the SDK referenced?  This is crucial.

Comment: updated... and here's the SDK ref: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (Single Sign-on with the JavaScript SDK)

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that I double-included the jQuery library into the Sub.aspx for testing...which is a no-no but did not know how to reference the parent's include or did not know if that's how you do that.  So probably conflicting if you have loaded 2 of the same file for the jQuery library??

Comment: @coffee In my answer I explain how to reference it.

Comment: yea I know..I'm just "thinking out loud" about it the wrong way...wondering what COULD be causing this problem without applying the parent.jQuery(); yet.  I've gone now though and added the parent.jQuery(); already to my Sub.aspx as a line of code in my JS section.  I did not ask how, I was thinking about if you did have 2 loaded what would be the result of that if any...anything would blow up possible with including the jQuery library twice.  Read my replies carefully ;)

Comment: But I'd be getting JS errors if anything was conflicting or the library was missing anyway so it makes no sense still why this is not working..my original problem.

Comment: weird, trying to add that jQuery include to my sub.  So my include is in the MasterPage.aspx, not the first parent up from the Subt.aspx which would be Main.aspx.  so in my MasterPage.aspx I've got <link href="~/content/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> but I don't see how to reference that using .jQuery()

Comment: thanks for the help.  I still cant' get that include script using jQuery() to work..anyway thanks.